# VBA macro bug "Something went wrong that might make PowerPoint Unstable"

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am fairly new to VBA and i am working on a script which list the file name of ppts in the source folder. It then loops through each slide in each ppt, extracts the text in a named text box and stores the string in a worksheet (Along with the slide index with the text is from).
The script then finds the unique strings and stores them in an array. Then for each unique string, it grabs a ppt template, saves a copy with the name of the unique string and copies the slides from the source ppts where the string is mentioned, then saves the new ppt in the output folder. If a file already exists with the name of the string then the scripts opens this file and copies over the slides from the source ppts.

When the script has to generate target ppts greater than ~ 10 ppts, a bug in ppt is triggered saying "We're sorry something went wrong that might make PowerPoint Unstable. Please save your presentations and restart PowerPoint."

If i click "okay" then the script carries on running, until another 5-6 target ppts are generated, and this continues.

I am unable to stop the code in excel at the exact line which this occurs as the message occurs from ppt, and as mentioned, when i click okay the code carries on running.

```
Sub CreateNewPPTForeachPN(lPNinitialLastRow As Long, iOutputRowCounter As Long, ppApp As PowerPoint.Application, oFSO As Object)

Dim ii As Long
Dim jj As Long
Dim ppTarget As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim ppSource As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim ppTemp As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim ppConsol As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim sAllPNs() As Variant
Dim sProcess As String
Dim sUniquePN() As String
Dim sUniqueFileNames() As String
Dim sFileNameSummary As String
Dim iFileNameCounter As Long
Dim iArrayCounter As Long
Dim sNewPPTName As String
Dim icounter As Long
Dim IrowCount As Long
Dim lNewLastRow As Long

IrowCount = wsPartNumberLog.Cells(1, 3).End(xlDown).Row
lNewLastRow = lPNinitialLastRow + 1


sAllPNs() = wsPartNumberLog.Range("C" & lNewLastRow, "C" & IrowCount).Value
'sAllPNs() = wsPartNumberLog.Cells(lNewLastRow, 3).Resize(IrowCount - lNewLastRow + 1, 1).Value
'sAllPNs() = wsPartNumberLog.Range(wsPartNumberLog.Cells(3, lNewLastRow), wsPartNumberLog.Cells(3, IrowCount)).Value


sUniquePN = ExtractUniqueValues(sAllPNs(), lNewLastRow)


For iArrayCounter = LBound(sUniquePN) To UBound(sUniquePN)
    
    sNewPPTName = sUniquePN(iArrayCounter)
    
    'Find unique SfileName associated with unique PN
    sUniqueFileNames = FindUniqueFileNamesSourceForPN(IrowCount, sNewPPTName)
    sFileNameSummary = ""
    
    'Populate summary with every unique File with unique PN
    For iFileNameCounter = LBound(sUniqueFileNames) To UBound(sUniqueFileNames)
        sFileNameSummary = sFileNameSummary & sUniqueFileNames(iFileNameCounter) & vbNewLine
    Next iFileNameCounter
    
    
    Call OpenPPTifNotOpened(ppApp)
    
    
    'Check for file existence
    If oFSO.fileexists(wsOptions.Range("Opt_sTarget").Value & "\" & sNewPPTName & ".pptx") Then
        
    
        'Get existing file
        Set ppConsol = Getppt(wsOptions.Range("Opt_sTarget").Value & "\" & sNewPPTName & ".pptx", ppApp)
        
        With ppConsol
            .Slides(1).Shapes("Date Placeholder 7").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Date
            .Slides(2).Shapes("Content Placeholder 9").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = sFileNameSummary
            
            For icounter = lNewLastRow To IrowCount
                If wsPartNumberLog.Cells(icounter, 3) = sNewPPTName Then
                    
                    Set ppSource = ppApp.Presentations.Open(wsOptions.Range("Opt_Spath") & "\" & wsPartNumberLog.Cells(icounter, 2).Value, ReadOnly:=msoTrue) 'Add read only option to GetFilesFromSource
                    Call InsertSlide_Source(ppConsol, ppSource.Slides(wsPartNumberLog.Cells(icounter, 4).Value))
                    ppSource.Close
                    Set ppSource = Nothing

                End If
            
            Next icounter
            
            'OutputFiles Log
            
            wsOutputLog.Cells(iOutputRowCounter + 1, 1).Value = iOutputRowCounter
            wsOutputLog.Cells(iOutputRowCounter + 1, 2).Value = ppConsol.Name
            wsOutputLog.Cells(iOutputRowCounter + 1, 3).Value = ppConsol.Slides.Count
            wsOutputLog.Cells(iOutputRowCounter + 1, 4).Value = Now()
            iOutputRowCounter = iOutputRowCounter + 1
            
            'Save new powerpoint
            ppConsol.Save
            ppConsol.Close
            
            'ppApp.Quit
            Set ppApp = Nothing
            
        End With
    
    Else
            
        'get the template
        Set ppTemp = Getppt(wsOptions.Range("Opt_Temp").Value, ppApp)
        
        'Populate the template with the relevant information related to the unique PN
        With ppTemp
            .SaveAs wsOptions.Range("Opt_sTarget").Value & "\" & sNewPPTName, ppSaveAsDefault
            .Slides(1).Shapes("Title 1").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = sNewPPTName & "_Consolidated Slides"
            .Slides(1).Shapes("Date Placeholder 7").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Date
            .Slides(2).Shapes("Content Placeholder 9").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = sFileNameSummary
            
            'For every new occurence of the PN in the workbook, open the source ppt and copy to the new ppt
            For icounter = 2 To IrowCount
                
                If wsPartNumberLog.Cells(icounter, 3) = sNewPPTName Then
                    
                    Set ppSource = ppApp.Presentations.Open(wsOptions.Range("Opt_Spath") & "\" & wsPartNumberLog.Cells(icounter, 2).Value, ReadOnly:=msoTrue)
                    Call InsertSlide_Source(ppTemp, ppSource.Slides(wsPartNumberLog.Cells(icounter, 4).Value))
                    ppSource.Close
                    Set ppSource = Nothing
                    
                End If
            
            Next icounter
                        
            'OutputFiles Log
            
            wsOutputLog.Cells(iOutputRowCounter + 1, 1).Value = iOutputRowCounter
            wsOutputLog.Cells(iOutputRowCounter + 1, 2).Value = ppTemp.Name
            wsOutputLog.Cells(iOutputRowCounter + 1, 3).Value = ppTemp.Slides.Count
            wsOutputLog.Cells(iOutputRowCounter + 1, 4).Value = Now()
            iOutputRowCounter = iOutputRowCounter + 1
            
            'Save new powerpoint
            ppTemp.Save
            ppTemp.Close
            
            'ppApp.Quit
            Set ppApp = Nothing


            
        End With
        
    End If
        

Next iArrayCounter



End Sub
```

Based on what i have found online, I cleaned up my registry and cleaned the computer.
I have disabled my anti virus to see if that helps.
I have tried using application.wait method to delay the copy section of the loop.
I have tried quitting and reopening ppApp every time before a target ppt is created.
I have tried opening up 2 instances of ppApp, one to deal with the source files and one to deal with the target file, but that doesn't work.

Can anyone please suggest some workarounds or solutions?

Comment: Just had a quick read of your problem. My first thought is that there might be too many "target ppts" open. When working with files in general you should always check that your "filestream" the action of writing into a file is finished at some point. In your case the bug might happen because lots of ppts are opened and written into but never closed. Just a first thought, I'll analyze the problem a bit more

Comment: you can check if my thought is correct by enabling the option to see hidden files in windows inside the directory where youre creating the target ppts. When working on ppts a hidden ppt is created. If those hidden files persist then you are not correctly closing them

Comment: ... I just realized those temporary hidden files are best visible when working on the desktop if thats an option for you...